# Basis of finite coproduct in the category of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

If we have the direct sum $V_1 \oplus ... \oplus V_d$ with inclusions $\iota_j$, of vector spaces $V_1, ..., V_d$ with bases $\mathcal{B}_j$, we 'know' from the construction that $V_1 \oplus ... \oplus V_d$ has basis $\{\iota_j(b) \ | \ 1 \leq j \leq d, b \in \mathcal{B}_j\}$. However, it is not obvious to me how we prove this without referencing to a construction and using uniqueness up to isomorphism.

The main problem I have is that we do not have an easy way to describe elements of objects (we can work with generalised elements, so morphisms $1 \to V_j$, but that gets even uglier than just working with the construction).

Is there a good way to show that this is a basis?

Comment: Picking a basis for a (finite dimensional) $k$-vector space $V$ is equivalent to picking an isomorphism $k^n\simeq V$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_\lambda$ be an arbitrary coproduct of vector spaces and denote by $j_\lambda\colon V_\lambda\to V$ the structure maps of the coproduct.

By definition of coproduct we know that whenever we have linear maps $f_\lambda\colon V_\lambda\to U$, then there exists a unique linear map $f\colon V\to U$ such that $fj_\lambda=f_\lambda$ for every $\lambda\in\Lambda$.

Just for the scope of this argument, call *admissible* a family $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$, where $x_\lambda\in V_\lambda$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$ and $\{\lambda\in\Lambda:x_\lambda\ne0\}$ is finite.

**First important fact.** Suppose you're given an admissible family such that $\sum_{\lambda}j_\lambda(x_\lambda)=0$.

Fix $\mu\in\lambda$ and define $f_\lambda\colon V_\lambda\to V_\mu$ to be the identity if $\lambda=\mu$ and the zero map if $\lambda\ne\mu$. Then we can consider $f\colon V\to V_\mu$ as above. We have
$$
0=f\Bigl(\,\sum_{\lambda}j_\lambda(x_\lambda)\Bigr)=\sum_{\lambda}f_\lambda(x_\lambda)=x_\mu
$$
**Second important fact.** If $x\in V$, then there exists an admissible family $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ such that
$$
x=\sum_{\lambda}j_{\lambda}(x_\lambda)
$$
(because the set of such sums satisfies the definition of coproduct).

Can you now prove that if you take a basis $\mathscr{B}_\lambda$ of $V_\lambda$, for each $\lambda$, then
$$
\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{\lambda}j_\lambda(\mathscr{B}_\lambda)
$$
is a basis of $V$?

Hints: the second fact proves $\mathscr{B}$ is a spanning set, the first fact proves it is linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks. So the linear independence follows from taking an admissible family of basis elements, and spanning because $x = \sum_{\lambda} j_\lambda(\sum_k a_k e_k) = \sum_{\lambda} \sum_{k} a_k j_{\lambda}(e_k)$ right? (For $e_k$ basis elements.)

Comment: Actually, I do still have a question about the spanning part. Aren't we constructing $V$ using maps $j_\lambda: V_{\lambda} \to V$, which is circular?

Comment: @PeldePinda There is no circularity; this is independent on the way you build the coproduct.